# OOP - Can a part of the application you are designing also be an actor?

Tags: oop, object

I am studying Object Oriented Design and am using usecases with actors and scenario''s to plan out the application i am trying to build. No specific language yet, just the theory at the moment.

I have come to the point where i have identified and written out the use cases for the users, administrator, owner, etc and also the external systems like the feed generator.
but i have come to realise that my application actually consists of multiple smaller apps. like a data gathering application and a analysis application.

Can/should i use the data gathering and analysis app as an actor in the overall application too?
I can write specific use cases for them, with scenarios etc.

Comment: Hmm, this question might be a better fit for Programmers SE; and I am not sure whether you have described your application in enough detail to allow anyone else to make sound recommendations about its overall architecture (but I might be wrong on that point).

Answer (score 1):

Typically, no.

Actor is an entity that sits outside of the system and produces some action. It gets to the system boundaries, but then all interactions between system components are modeled not as usecases, but as i.e. dynamic diagrams or sequence diagrams.

For the record, I think this approach is flawed and doesn't really help you in building applications. I personally prefer thinking about components and their interactions directly, without forcing the idea of architecture to fit a particular modeling scheme.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i am studying the fundamentals and it was explained there like that. Sequence diagrams we havent touched yet so i might be jumping the gun here.